# Mysql Changes to /etc/mysql/my.cnf not working

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-1064

I am facing a issue with mysql. I am a beginner.

I installed mysql on Ubuntu.
After installation when I ran 
    sudo service mysql status
It showed that it had started.

Now since the bindaddress is 127.0.0.1, I changes it to 0.0.0.0
After making changes to /etc/mysql/my.cnf, when i save and restart the mysql by running the command:
sudo service mysql restart
It hangs sometimes for a long time.
Sometimes, it says that it has started the mysql server. However when I run
ps -ef | grep mysql
I cannot see mysqld running.

What do I need to include or make changes to?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your log file in your mysql directory for more information?  It should be named "YOUR_MACHINE_NAME.err."

Comment: If you're using an InnoDb database, you'll want to check that your InnoDb values are enabled in your my.cnf file.  Also, if it's not a problem to clear your table's data, you can try deleting your ibdata and ib_logfile files, and then restarting mysql.

Comment: Is it the log file present in /var/log/mysql? It is named error.log?
It does not seem to show any abnormalities.

Comment: No, it should end with ".err".  But the location sounds correct.

Comment: I have freshly installed it. SO I do not have any data. Where can I find these log files? ibdata and ib_logfile files ?

Comment: No, It says error.log. SHould I try removing and Installing it once again?

Comment: It is so happening that. When I change the mode(permission) of /etc/mysql/my.cnf I am unable to restart or start the mysql service. I am not making any changes to the file, only changing the mode like this: chmod o+w /etc/mysql/my.cnf

How should I go about changing the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file? It is write protected.Where am I going wrong?

Comment: ibdata and ib_logfile are in your mysql folder.  These are created if you have innodb data.  If you don't, they won't exist.

Comment: Also, you may want to check that all of your data folders and files in your mysql directory have their group and user set to "mysql"

Comment: I am now able to change the bindaddress in the file to 0.0.0.0 and run the service. However now I am facing a new issue, I am running two VMs and I have SQL running on one of them. And when i try to connect to this from my another VM, it is not allowing me to connect.
It says "Host is not allowed to connect to this server".

Comment: You may need to grant access to the user from that server....

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on *.* to 'root'@'%.home' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if I need to grant access to all Databases and to any user?